# How to rename 'C:\Users' folder in windows

Tags: windows, rename, administrator, mount, ntfs

I have 2 HDDs, I am tring to mount the 2nd HDD to an empty NTFS folder `C:\Users` or `C:\Users\<username>` *(which is not empty)*. 
My approach: is to rename that folder to temporary name, then mount 2nd HDD to Users folder *(which I would create and It would be empty)*, then copy all Data to the new created folder *(which is the 2nd HDD)*, then delete the temporary named folder. 
Unfortunately, it's not like in linux where you are able to do so as super user

**I know it's possible to rename it when booting to another OS, but I won't be able to mount the 2nd HDD to new empty NTFS folder as I understand**

I tried to use Admin CMD `ren Users Users.old`, but I got access denied error. 
I also tried to rename the username folder itself via CMD but I got the same error.